# Representation of Church numerals

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computer-science, computability, lambda-calculus

In the $\lambda$-calculus, is the family of $\lambda$-terms $(N_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$, defined below, a representation of Church numerals? I think it is, but how do I (sufficiently) show it? If not, what is it?

The terms $N_i$ and $N'_i$ for each natural number $i$ are defined as follows. ($x$ and $c$ are variables while $i$ stands for a number.)
\begin{align}
          N'_0 &= x
\\
          N'_i &= c \,i\, N'_{i−1} &&\text{for } i > 0
\\
          N_i &= \lambda c. \lambda x. N'_i &&\text{for any }i \in \mathbb{N}
\end{align}

Comment: I don't understand the definition of $N_i' = c \, i \, N_{i-1}'$. Indeed, $i$ is a natural number, not a $\lambda$-term, so $N_i'$ would not be a $\lambda$-term. Maybe do you mean $N_i'= c \, N_{i-1}'$?

Comment: First off @Taroccoesbrocco, what do you use to get such nice formatting? To answer your question: what if in addition to i being a number (as stated)  it was also its Church encoding?

Comment: To write mathematical notations with a nice and readable layout, please use [MathJax](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation). A quick tutorial is [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/288417). It takes a bit of time to become familiar with it, but it helps a lot yourself and your readers.

Comment: If $i$ is not only a natural number but also the Church numeral representing $i$, then your question becomes an abstract nonsense. In your question you're defining Church numerals inductively, but in the definition of $N_i'$ (which is mandatory to define then the Church numeral for $i$) you assume that the Church for $i$ is already defined. An unsolvable vicious circle.

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco well to avoid nonsense perhaps lets go with your initial suggestion of a correction. I really appreciate your time helping me here!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Disclaimer*. I assume that the inductive definition of the $\lambda$-terms $(N_n')_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ given in the original question, i.e.,
\begin{align}
N_0' &= x 
\\
N_n' &= f \, n \, N_{n-1}' &\text{if } n > 0
\end{align}

contains a typo: $N_n'$ should be defined as $f \, N_{n-1}'$ when $n > 0$, because $n$ is a natural number and not a $\lambda$-term, so the expression$f \, n \, N_{n-1}'$ does not make any sense in the $\lambda$-calculus. My answer below considers the amended version of that definition.

---

*[Church numerals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_encoding)* are the $\lambda$-terms used to encode natural numbers in the $\lambda$-calculus.

Usually, for every natural number $n$, the Church numeral $\underline{n}$ representing $n$ is defined as the $\lambda$-term
$$\tag{1}
\underline{n} = \lambda f. \lambda x. f^n x = \lambda f. \lambda x. \overbrace{f(f( \cdots (f}^{n \text{ times }}x)\cdots))
$$
($f^n x$ is just a shorthand for $\overbrace{f(f( \cdots (f}^{n \text{ times }}x)\cdots))$, for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$).

This definition is slightly informal because it uses dots, which$-$strictly speaking$-$are not in the syntax of the $\lambda$-calculus.
How can we define Church numerals in a more rigorous way?

As human beings, we are perfectly able to understand what dots mean. If we fix $n \in \mathbb{N}$, from $(1)$ we are able to write the concrete Church numeral for $n$. For instance:
\begin{align}
\underline{0} &= \lambda f. \lambda x. x 
&
\underline{1} &= \lambda f. \lambda x. fx
&
\underline{4} &= \lambda f. \lambda x. f(f(f(fx)))
\end{align}
So, for the usual practice, definition $(1)$ is perfect.
But if we want to write a very rigorous proof of a property of the $\lambda$-calculus involving *all* Church numerals, what do we do? Are we sure that dots cannot hide some pathological and unexpected behavior of Church numerals?

This search for a more rigorous definition is not only a pedantic issue, but it is of practical interest.
Suppose that  we want to implement the $\lambda$-calculus in a computer, for instance to use automated theorem provers to verify some property of the $\lambda$-calculus involving Church numerals.
How can a computer understand dots?

In mathematics, when you use dots to define an object, it usually means that the object is defined by *induction*.
In the case of Church numerals, we proceed by induction on $n \in \mathbb{N}$.
Actually, in $(1)$ dots appear only in the $f^n x$ part, so the inductive definition is required only for a rigorous definition of
$$\tag{2}
f^n x = \overbrace{f(f( \cdots (f}^{n \text{ times }}x)\cdots))
$$
Formally, for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ we define the $\lambda$-term $N_n'$ by induction on $n$ as follows:
\begin{align}
N_0' &= x &&\text{(base case)}
\\
N_{n}' &= f \, N_{n-1}' &&\text{(inductive step, for $n > 0$)}
\end{align}

What is the relation between this inductive definition and $(2)$?

*Property.* For every $n \in \mathbb{N}$, we have
$$\tag{3}
f^n x = N_n'.
$$

*Proof.* By induction on $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

- *Base case* ($n = 0$):
  $$
  f^0 x = \overbrace{f(f( \cdots (f}^{0 \text{ times }}x)\cdots)) = x = N_0'.
  $$
- *Inductive step*: We suppose that property $(3)$ holds for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$ (induction hypothesis, IH) and we show that it holds for $n+1$.

$$
f^{n+1} x = \overbrace{f(f( \cdots (f}^{n+1 \text{ times }}x)\cdots)) = f \,(\overbrace{f(f( \cdots (f}^{n \text{ times }}x)\cdots))) = f (f^n x)  \overset{\text{IH}}{=} f \, N_{n}' = N_{n+1}'. \quad \square
$$

We have just proved $(3)$, that is, that for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ the $\lambda$-term $f^nx$ defined via dots in $(2)$ is the same as the $\lambda$-term $N_n'$ defined inductively.
From $(3)$ it follows that Church numerals defined in $(1)$ are exactly the same as the $\lambda$-terms $(N_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ defined as follows:

\begin{align}
N_n &= \lambda f. \lambda x. N_n' &\text{for every } n \in \mathbb{N}.
\end{align}

Indeed, for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$, we have
$$\underline{n} = \lambda f. \lambda x. f^n x \overset{(3)}{=} \lambda f. \lambda x. N_n' = N_n.
$$